# NSLocale force a calendar type

Tags: ios, swift, nslocale

`[NSLocale currentLocale]` may returns `<__NSCFLocale: 0x7ff708516540> 'en_US@calendar=japanese'}`

Question: can I say NSLocale do not append `calendar=japanese` to locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
   NSString *lang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"language is %@", lang);

  NSString   *langua = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];
  NSLog(@" specified language is %@", langua);

  NSString   *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
  NSLog(@"specified countryCode is %@", countryCode);
```

the output like

[image]

**Swift**

```
var lang = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]

let langua = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String
let countryCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
```

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm